# terraform loop with a conditional key inside an object

Tags: loops, for-loop, terraform, terragrunt

let's suppose we have this variable:

```
  foobars = {
    "first" : {
      specialkeys: [
        "a",
        "b",
        "c"
      ]
    }
    "second" : {}
  }
```

now let's say we would like to loop over that foobars object knowing that **specialkeys** doesn't exist in the "**second**" object.

This is what I tried but it complains that

```
This object does not have an attribute named specialkeys
```

My tries:

```
  data = flatten([
    for k, v in var.foobars : [
      for sk in v.specialkeys : {
          special = sk,
          foo = k
      }
    ]
  ])
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would want to do the following:

```
data = flatten([
    for k, v in local.foobars :
    [
      for sk, sv in v :
      [
        for spec in sv : {
          special = spec,
          foo     = k
        }
      ]
    ]
  ])
```

This will output something like this:

```
[
  {
    "foo" = "first"
    "special" = "a"
  },
  {
    "foo" = "first"
    "special" = "b"
  },
  {
    "foo" = "first"
    "special" = "c"
  },
]
```